# vuejs animate list items inside grid

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, vuejs2

I have generated list items inside a grid, using vuejs I am dynamically updating the content of a cell inside a grid by changing the class name. I want to change the element inside the cell using css3 animation. Using transition-group I have applied css animation but its not working correctly, as css class is applied it create new element which drops to the next line then it hides the previous element. How can I animate in place right inside the cell?

here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/274/

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <transition-group tag="div" name="fade" class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-1-2" v-for="item in thumbs" :key="item.id">
      <div class="item">
        <i class="fa" :class="item.icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to hide the previous icon:

```
.fade-enter-active {
  display: none;
}
```

[Here is updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/275/)

Comment: there is still some flick effect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
.item {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: opacity .5s;
    animation: fade .5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/1338/

I removed transition from html and add simple keyframe animation.